# Autowiring Beans in Custom instance of Jackson StdDeserializer

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, jackson, json-deserialization

I have a request object using a custom deserializer for a member of object

```
@JsonDeserialize(using = SomeClassDeserializer.class)
private SomeClass someClass;
```

Spring Boot does not autowire annotated fields by default even if the class is annotated with `@Component` because Jackson handles the instantiation. How do I work around preserving the default constructors needed by Jackson, and injecting beans for use in the Deserializer?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found the answer lies with a third constructor using the conventional `@Autowired` annotation and injecting the required bean this way. However, instead of using the typical instance of member assignment, declare the field as static and assign this injected bean to all instances of the deserializer generated by Jackson. It's kind of a hacky workaround, but it solved issue for me.

```
public class SomeClassDeserializer extends StdDeserializer<SomeObject> {
    private static SomeUtil someUtil;

    public SomeClassDeserializer(Class<?> vc) {
        super(vc);
    }

    public SomeClassDeserializer() {
        this(null);
    }

    @Autowired
    public SomeClassDeserializer(SomeUtil someUtil) {
        this(null);
        SomeClassDeserializer.someUtil= someUtil;
    }
```

Comment: andrewdleach, i am facing the same problem that you mentioned, can you please provide your code for the resolution that you achieved above.

Comment: @user2917559 see amended answer

Answer (score 0):

```
public class SomeClassDeserializer extends StdDeserializer<SomeObject> {

    @Autowired
    private  SomeUtil someUtil;

    public SomeClassDeserializer(Class<?> vc) {
        super(vc);
    }

    public SomeClassDeserializer() {
        this(null);
    }

  /*  @Autowired
    public SomeClassDeserializer(SomeUtil someUtil) {
        this(null);
        SomeClassDeserializer.someUtil= someUtil;
    }*/
```

I have a question as to why we cannot do this instead of the answer above

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).